# Lite and simple database management program for windows?

Tags: windows, localhost

I own a data entry and lead generation company. I've developed a system for my people to make their job more easy. This system includes multiple browser and browser extensions that work simultaneously in the same computer. All I need is a lite weight and simple database program/ system  so the browser can share/scan each other's data. (I don't need to share data with other computers on the local network.)

Currently I am using IIS, PHP and MySQL to complete the task. But it is very painful to install/setup all these on a new PC everytime.

I'm wondering if there is any app/system that will be more easy for me. I appreciate your help.

[I know php,python,javascript,jquery,mysql only]